# Как упростить словарь и код?

Tags: python, dict

В импровизированной игре(типа камень-ножницы-бумага,с правилами как на картинке) задача состоит в том,чтобы написать програму, которая по двум строчкам(выбор первого и второго игрока соответственно) будет выводить победителя,ну или ничью.

```py
player1, player2 = input(), input()
d = {('камень', 'ножницы'): 'первый',
     ('камень', 'ром'): 'первый',
     ('камень', 'бумага'): 'второй',
     ('камень', 'пират'): 'второй',
     ('бумага', 'камень'): 'первый',
     ('бумага', 'пират'): 'первый',
     ('бумага', 'ножницы'): 'второй',
     ('бумага', 'ром'): 'второй',
     ('ножницы', 'бумага'): 'первый',
     ('ножницы', 'ром'): 'первый',
     ('ножницы', 'камень'): 'второй',
     ('ножницы', 'пират'): 'второй',
     ('пират', 'камень'): 'первый',
     ('пират', 'ножницы'): 'первый',
     ('пират', 'бумага'): 'второй',
     ('пират', 'ром'): 'второй',
     ('ром', 'бумага'): 'первый',
     ('ром', 'пират'): 'первый',
     ('ром', 'камень'): 'второй',
     ('ром', 'ножницы'): 'второй'}

if player1 == player2:
    print('ничья')
else:
    print(d[(player1, player2)])
```

Код который я написал рабочий,но кажется громоздким.Подскажите,можно ли упростить код,сделать более элегантным?Если да,то как?Упростить содержание словаря или поменять принцип работы.Заранее спасибо! [image: Схема игры]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Можно сократить количество элементов словаря

```
d = {
    'ножницы': ('бумага', 'ром'),
    'бумага': ('камень', 'пират'),
    'камень': ('ром', 'ножницы'),
    'ром': ('пират', 'бумага'),
    'пират': ('ножницы', 'камень'),
}

print('ничья' if player1 == player2
      else 'первый' if player2 in d[player1]
      else 'второй')
```

А можно и вовсе решить без него

```
lst = ['ножницы', 'бумага', 'камень', 'ром', 'пират']
index = lst.index(player1)

print('ничья' if player1 == player2
      else 'первый' if player2 in (lst[index - 2], lst[index - 4])
      else 'второй')
```